# what is the diffrence between getClientOriginalExtension() and Extension() in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Both methods returns the extention of the uploaded file, so why they both existe ?
Can't find any diffrence between them.

Comment: Extension is a function of Laravel's `Filesystem` class, while `getOriginalClientExtension` is a function of `UploadedFile` (a Symfony Component): https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L399 vs https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php#L94. You can use those links to inspect what each function is actually doing.

Comment: No problem   Also, here's a very helpful link: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/, lets you search for anything and will provide a code reference for most Classes, Attributes, Functions, etc.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you again, yup, their docs are just awesome

Comment: Haha, having worked with languages/frameworks that have... let's say "less than awesome" documentation, I am very thankful that Laravel's is the way it is. Cheers again 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These methods are available on every `\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`.

`getClientOriginalExtension()` returns the extension extracted from the original file name. If you send `image.png`, it'll be `png`

`extension()` returns the extension extracted from the file itself (using the mime type).

For instance, if you have a `image.pdf` file, you rename it `image.png` and then you upload it to your app:

- `getClientOriginalExtension()` will return `png`
- `extension()` will return `pdf` (or `null` if the mime type cannot be read)

Comment: I made a mistake, you were talking about `extension()` and not `getExtension()`. They are very similar but I updated my answer so it is more accurate.

Comment: yeah I see, I thought it was just a typo, anyway, thanx again

Comment: It might be worth adding that `getClientOriginalExtension` should never be trusted to determine a file's type, due to how easily clients can lie about a file's extension.

Answer (score 1):

`getClientOriginalExtension` gets **CLIENT** extension, not the real mime-type extension, to get that use `extension` it is more secure